# How to override a variadic template with lambda as the first parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

Why doesn't the following function override (lambda as a first parameter) work?

```
template<typename ...Args>
void call(Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "call 1";
}

template<typename ...Args>
void call(CustomObject object, Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "call 2";
}

// see this function
template<typename ...Args>
void call(std::function<void ()>, Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "call 3";
}
```

- `call()` output *‘call 1’*
- `call(CustomObject())` output *'call 2'*
- `call([](){})` output *'call 1'* // **wrong**

Why does `call([](){})` not output *'call 3'*?

How should I declare the function to let `call([](){})` output *'call 3'*?

**EDIT:** @KennyTM gave the answer for the above.

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto call(F&& f, Args&& ...args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(f()), void>::value>::type
{
    std::cout << "call 3\n";
}
```

---

But... What if the lambda has a parameter? Like this:

```
class CustomObject {};

template<typename ...Args>
void call(std::function<void (CustomObject *)>, Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "call 4";
}
```

How to let `call([](CustomObject *){})` output *'call 4'*?

**EDIT:** @ildjarn gave the answer:

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto call(F&& f, Args&& ...)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(f( std::declval<CustomObject*>() )), void>::value>::type
{
    std::cout << "call 4\n";
}
```

Comment: A _lambda_ is _convertible_ to `std::function`, so the first function is a better match.

Comment: I test it in xcode 4.5, with apple llvm compiler 4.1

Comment: @K-ballo, but isn't `std::function<void ()>` the type for this lambda?

Comment: @smilingpopular: No, each lambda has a different _implementation specified_ type.. It's only _convertible_ to `std::function`

Comment: @K-ballo, but `std::function` is a template. How should I correct my function declaration?

Comment: @smilingpoplar : "*How to let `call([](CustomObject *){})` output 'call 4'?*" The corrected code is here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2LLpoa$0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lambda's type is an anonymous type which has an `operator()`. It is not a `std::function<>`.

Instead of specializing the type, you could check if the first argument is a functor for call 3 (demo: http://ideone.com/IQ4N6L):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
auto call(F&& f, Args&& ...args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(f()), void>::value>::type
{
    std::cout << "call 3\n";
}


template<typename ...Args>
void call(Args&& ...args) {
    std::cout << "call 1\n";
}



int main() {
    call(1);
    call([](){});
}
```